# How to get an ActiveX component's registered path

Tags: c#, com, activex, regsvr32

I've got a registered ActiveX component which I'm referencing in a C# project. However, I'd like to know the original path to the actual component being run. This is not the execution path per se. Is there something saner than searching the registry by hand?

The component is registered with a simple /regserver command, if that's relevant.

Comment: So this is an out-of-proc server? Can you add a property (ProcessID) to a class?

Comment: Yes, out-of-process. However, I can't edit the server itself, it's compiled and source-less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search under the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID` with the name of your EXE file. It should be used as value of "LocalServer32".

Comment: Thanks. I found that out through sifting in the Registry. My objective was to avoid doing that, though :P

Comment: there are so many ways to read `HKCR\CLSID\<clsid>\LocalServer32` by using popular programming languages that, imho, a standalone tool for that is not required. Non-programmers can use `reg query`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that fetches the value out of the Registry. Extra validation required.

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

//...
static string GetCOMPath(string comName)
{
    RegistryKey comKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(comName + "\\CLSID");
    string clsid = (string)comKey.GetValue("");
    comKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("CLSID\\" + clsid + "\\LocalServer32");
    return (string)comKey.GetValue("");
}
```

However, I was wondering if that wasn't already wrapped somewhere in some lost C# library...