# How do I get the location of a registered .NET component using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

In Visual Studio you can reference registered .NET components. I need to get the location (full path) of one of these components at runtime. Can I realize that (in C#)?

I do not reference that .NET assembly in my project. I just want to get the location of a registered .NET assembly, like it is listed in the window, that is shown when I want to add a reference.

Comment: Are you talking about items in the toolbox, add reference dialog, etc ...?

Comment: Are you asking for the path to an assembly in the GAC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is it that you are trying to do?

If you want to determine at runtime the path of an assembly then try this:

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Form)).Location
// Output:
// C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

You should replace "Form" with a type in the assembly that you wish to locate (e.g. `string`) for mscorlib.dll.

Comment: this will return GAC path, not the original location of assembly

Comment: @Farzin What do you mean by "The original location of the assembly?" If the assembly is loaded from the GAC, then that is the path that will be returned.

Comment: but the main assembly location witch is registered in GAC is different. to find that real path, he should read registry.

Comment: @Farzin What do you mean by the "real" path? If the assembly is loaded from the GAC then what other path is more "real" than the one that the assembly is actually loaded from?

Comment: thanks, but I haven't refernced that .NET component, so I cannot use "typeof".

Comment: @iDog I'm really confused, what are you trying to do exactly?  There are various ways of loading an assembly (and consequently finding its location by) name, I don't know which to suggest as I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry it's late in germany ;) I just want to get the location of a .NET component that is listed in the window, which is shown, when I add a reference. The point is, I want to do that at runtime. For example: How do I get the location of the "System.Core" DLL at runtime? In my case, I need to get the location of a .NET component, which is registered by a non-microsoft software. Now clear? :)

Comment: By the way, I need to get that location, but in my project I don't reference that DLL

Comment: @iDog The easiest way of doing this is probably to load the assembly and use the Location of the loaded assembly.  In case this won't work then this link [How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=VS.100).aspx) may help to identify a 3rd party component that appears in the References list by looking at the registry.

Answer (score 2):

```
Assembly.GetAssembly([C#_Component].GetType()).Location
```

Comment: this will return GAC path, not the original location of assembly

Comment: @Farzin If it is loaded from the GAC... at runtime there is no other location

Comment: I haven't refernced that .NET component, so I cannot use "GetType". There must be a way to get the location without to reference that Dll?!

Comment: Ah, Google for Fusion API for COM then, it has the tools you need

Answer (score 2):

Search under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID with the name of your EXE file. It should be used as value of "LocalServer32".

You just need to read the registry for this.

Reference: Stack Overflow question *[How to get an ActiveX component's registered path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055793/how-to-get-an-activex-components-registered-path)*

Comment: This only applies to COM objects - not all .Net assemblies expose COM objects and so many will not appear in this list.

Comment: +1, the question is too lousy to not make this an accurate answer